# minGW compilation warning for each g++

Tags: c++, mingw

I tried googling woht no luck, maybe someone encountered this

I'm using MinGW on my windows 7 32-bit machine (not sure about the version of MinGW, but the g++ version is g++ (GCC) 4.6.1)

I get the following warning for EACH compilation line:

```
command-line:0:16: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name
```

example for a compilation line:

```
g++ -c "-D__XXX_WINDOWS__;" -g -Wall -o "XXX.o" -Isrc "src/YYY.cpp"
```

Comment: g++ -c  "-D__XXX_WINDOWS__;" -g -Wall -o "XXX.o" -Isrc "src/YYY.cpp"
<command-line>:0:16: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name [enabled by default]

Comment: `"-D__XXX_WINDOWS__;"` is really strange. Why not just `-D__XXX_WINDOWS__`?

Comment: hmm... SlickEdit put it in... didn't notice it. Thanks

Comment: by the way - my bad, I put it in the SlickEdit window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `;` at the end of your `-D` switch.

The command you give is essentially equivalent to having:

```
#define foo;
```

at the to of your source. This does define `foo` to  `;`, but that's not valid C99 (and could be a typo). §6.10.3/3 from C99 draft n1124:

> There shall be white-space between the identifier and the replacement list in the definition of an object-like macro.

So the compiler warns you, or emits an error if you compile with  `-std=c99`.

(You can probably drop the quotes too once you've removed the semicolon.)